# How can I get current user ID using IHttpContextAccessor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, httpcontext

I am currently using .NET Core and I am trying to get the current user ID. I understand that `System.Web` is not available in NET Core, so I tried using `IHttpContextAccessor`.

I have also added this into my `Startup.cs`: `service.AddHttpContextAccessor()`

I then tried looking up for the user id by doing this in my controller:

```
public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor){
     var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
}
```

But it always returns null, does anyone knows why and able to advise? I have also disabled `anonymousAuthentication` and set `windowsAuthentication` to true.

**Edit**

The only changes I did to my `Startup.cs` is in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
   services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've included "ClaimTypes.Name" with the username value in claims when token was generated.
Then you can access the username using IHttpContextAccessor, if respective dependency is added, like:

```
var currentUserName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```

Then you can access the user like:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(currentUserName);
```

and hence the userId:

```
var userId = user.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you need `IHttpContextAccessor`?

There is a better way to get Id from claims actually:

You can use `ControllerBase.User` property, but at first make sure that your controller is derived from `Controller` or `ControllerBase` (last one is without views support).

[image: ControllerBase.User property]

```
public class YourController : Controller
    {
    ...

    var id = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)

    ...   
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I have tried the method you suggested, however, my `var id` is null.. any idea why?

Comment: @CodeName do you have authentication and authorization set up well? Can you share your `startup.cs`? Are you sure that user have claims at all?

Comment: Yes, when I did a `User.Identity.Name`, it does show up my PC username. Hold on a sec, let me add in my `Startup.cs` codes.

Comment: @CodeName seems like you use windows authentication, so you can inspect the `Identity` of a `User` and see that you have no claim for `NameIdentifier`.
Read this [article](https://philipm.at/2018/aspnetcore_claims_with_windowsauthentication.html), here you can find claims that you can get from `User` with your type of authentication

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to get Id from claims actually:

You can use the `ControllerBase.User` property, but at first, make sure that your controller is derived from Controller or ControllerBase (the last one is without views support).

Use the following code snippet to get ASPNET ID

```
string currentUser = _http.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList().Find(r => r.Type == "id").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. The easiest way to get an instance of this class is add it as an argument to your class constructor and it will be provided via dependency injection.

```
string userId = UserManager.GetUserId(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
```

Don't forget to check for null values.